# NoMethodError when trying to setup Capistrano with WordPress Stacks

Tags: wordpress, capistrano3

I'm trying to run...

```
cap staging deploy:setup
```

and I'm getting this error. I'm not very familiar with terminal was following this tutorial to set this up - http://design.zhiwan.is/setting-up-mark-jaquiths-wp-stacks-and-wp-skeleton-for-capristrano-deployment/.

I've looked for solutions and ran through various attempts to resolve this issue. And input would be helpful.

```
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railsless-deploy-1.1.3/lib/railsless-deploy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
/Users/kylebebeau/websites/theinitgroup/Capfile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```